# I am new to Angularjs, just tried populating multiple json value but it's not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, mean-stack

```
        <div ng-controller="studentController" ng-repeat = "student in students | unique = 'RollNo' " > 
        <table  class="profile-info">
        <tr>
        <th>Roll No</th>
        <td>{{ student.RollNo }}</td>              
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th>Class</th>
        <td>{{ student.Class }}</td>              
        </tr>  
        <tr>
        <th>Section</th>
        <td>{{ student.Section }}</td>              
        </tr>   
        <tr>
        <th>Sports</th>
        <td>{{ student.Sports }}</td>              
        </tr>  
        <tr>
        <th>other Interests</th>
        <td>{{ student.otherInterests }}</td>              
        </tr>                  
        </table>
        </div>

    <---- Angular Part---->
// Not able to Populate the Json Value using the Follwing Script // 

    <script>
    function studentController($scope,$http) {
    var url = "aboutme.json";
    $http.get(url).success( function(response) {
    $scope.students = response.data;
    });
    }
    </script>

<--- JSON PART --- >
[
   {
      "Class" : 1,
      "RollNo" : 1,
      "Section" : "A",
      "Sports" : "Football",
      "otherInterests" : "Music",
   },

  {
      "Class" : 12,
      "RollNo" : 2,
      "Section" : "B",
      "Sports" : "Counter-Strike",
      "otherInterests" : "Music",
   }
]
```

Comment: Guru devji What is the error?

Comment: you even did typo with comma near : ng-repeat = "student in students | unique = "RollNo" "

Comment: before posting any code, you should make sure that there should not syntax error. It seems like you don't have even run it.

Comment: Actually i removed and tried executing it's not working

Comment: Actually i wanted to populate the Json values to the table but was not able to do so. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some small change you have to made in HTML.So, that `ng-repeat` will work as per your expextation.

1. Use `ng-repeat` on `tr` of td instead of whole `div`.
2. Make sure that `$scope.students` having the same `JSON` as shown in the `JSON part` in the post.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('studentController',function($scope) {
  $scope.students = [
   {
      "Class" : 1,
      "RollNo" : 1,
      "Section" : "A",
      "Sports" : "Football",
      "otherInterests" : "Music"
   },
  {
      "Class" : 12,
      "RollNo" : 2,
      "Section" : "B",
      "Sports" : "Counter-Strike",
      "otherInterests" : "Music"
   }
];
})
```

```css
table,th,td {
  border:1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="studentController"> 
<table class="profile-info">
    <tr>
        <th>Roll No</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Sports</th>
        <th>other Interests</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
        <td>{{ student.RollNo }}</td>              
        <td>{{ student.Class }}</td>   
        <td>{{ student.Section }}</td>   
        <td>{{ student.Sports }}</td>  
        <td>{{ student.otherInterests }}</td>
    </tr>                  
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks there was an syntax error in json part. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

See the code.. Hope this will help

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.students = [{ "Class" : 1, "RollNo" : 1, "Section" : "A", "Sports" : "Football", "otherInterests" : "Music", },

{ "Class" : 12, "RollNo" : 2, "Section" : "B", "Sports" : "Counter-Strike", "otherInterests" : "Music", } ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
        
        <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Roll Number</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Sports</th>
            <th>Other Intrests</th>
          <tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
            <td>{{student.Class}}</td>
            <td>{{student.RollNo}}</td>
            <td>{{student.Section}}</td>
            <td>{{student.Sports}}</td>
            <td>{{student.otherInterests}}</td>
          </tr>
                       
        </table>
        

</div>
```

Comment: Tried it's just showing {{student.Class}} for all in the frontend of the website

Comment: check your code you are missing something. check browsers console.. u ll find ur error...

Comment: Thanks for your  time ,it was typo in my JSON File

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="studentController" ng-repeat = "student in students | unique = "RollNo" " >
```

Change To

```
<div ng-controller="studentController" ng-repeat="student in students | unique = 'RollNo'" >
```

Or And

```
{ "Class" : 1, "RollNo" : 1, "Section" : "A", "Sports" : "Football", "otherInterests" : "Music", },
{ "Class" : 12, "RollNo" : 2, "Section" : "B", "Sports" : "Counter-Strike", "otherInterests" : "Music", } ]
```

Change To

```
{ "Class" : 1, "RollNo" : 1, "Section" : "A", "Sports" : "Football", "otherInterests" : "Music"},
{ "Class" : 12, "RollNo" : 2, "Section" : "B", "Sports" : "Counter-Strike", "otherInterests" : "Music", } ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time , I was a typo in the JSON File

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat to the tr not for div

```
<div ng-controller="studentController"  > 
        <table  class="profile-info">
        <tr><th>Roll No</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Section</th> 
            <th>Sports</th>  
            <th>other Interests</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat = "student in students | unique = 'RollNo' ">      
            <td>{{ student.RollNo }}</td>              
            <td>{{ student.Class }}</td>              
            <td>{{ student.Section }}</td>              
            <td>{{ student.Sports }}</td>              
            <td>{{ student.otherInterests }}</td>              
        </tr>                  
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Tried but no luck - Thanks for your time

Comment: check your console is there might be you getting some error post it here if any

Answer (score 0):

Open your DevTools (Press F12) to see the errors.
Moslt likely it is just the a typo in your JSON File.

```
[{ "Class" : 1, "RollNo" : 1, "Section" : "A", "Sports" : "Football", "otherInterests" : "Music"},
{ "Class" : 12, "RollNo" : 2, "Section" : "B", "Sports" : "Counter-Strike", "otherInterests" : "Music", }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the time,it was typo in my JSON File

Answer (score 0):

One issue will be that `ng-repeat` is on `div` instead of `tr`.

The other will be that you're calling `$http.get(...).success`. You need to call `$http.get(...).then`